# How do i point to default dummy record incase when foreign key is null

Tags: sql, join, hive, foreign-keys

I have query in which i join multiple dimension table to create fact table. For cases when foreign key is null i want to point it to default dummy records added in dimension tables so that there is no null value in the fields. How is it possible . Please help.

```
Select 
a.name,
a.id_no,
d.dealer_name,
d.address

from 
contract a
left join dealer b 
on a.con_id=b.con_id
```

For the above example when b.con_id is null and there is no match found in such cases i want to point to default foreign key(0) added in dealer table. Its is like if FK is null take default fk and use those record to fill the fields

Comment: Is it necessary to use a dummy record? AFAIK you can use COALESCE to specify a value if your column is null.

Comment: Yes. But according to kimball dataware house design this would be a standard practice

Comment: From what I read (assuming [#43](https://www.kimballgroup.com/2003/02/design-tip-43-dealing-with-nulls-in-the-dimensional-model/)) the result should not contain nulls, so coalesce would solve that problem.

Comment: Do your table contract  has row where a.con_id = 0? that case you can you the Joining condition as - on a.con_id=COALESCE(b.con_id ,0)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ISNULL()` in your query.

**For example:**

```
select * 
from table1 as a 
left join table2 as b on a.id = ISNULL(b.id, 0)
```

Comment: Be careful, this solution will never work because ISNULL is applied before join. Test it yourself and you will see. See my test: https://demo.gethue.com/hue/editor?editor=53578

Comment: `with a as (
select stack(3,
1,'val1',
2,'val2',
3,'val3'
) as (id, val)
),

b as (
select stack(3,
0,'val1',
2,'val2',
3,'val3'
) as (id, val)
)

select *
 from a left join b on a.id=nvl(b.id,0)` - this returns wrong result. It will newer work in such way

Answer (score 1):

You can take the approach of ensuring that each dimension table has a default row, say with `-1` as the value:

```
insert into dim_table (dim_table_id, . . . )
    values (-1, . . . );
```

Then in most databases, you can declare the reference as:

```
create table other_table (
    . . .,
    dim_table_id int not null default -1 references dim_table(dim_table_id)
    . . .
);
```

However, I don't think that Hive (yet) supports `default` values on columns.  So, you can do this but you need to explicitly insert the `-1` when you insert new rows into the referencing tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can **either** keep it as null **or** you can point the fact record to a dummy record showing there is no reference for it (With an id < 0 indicating it).

Answer (score 0):

You can substitute with  default values for not joined records like this:

```
Select 
a.name,
a.id_no,
case when d.con_id is null then 'Default Name' else d.dealer_name end dealer_name  ,
case when d.con_id is null then 'Default Address' else d.address  end address
from 
contract a
left join dealer d 
on a.con_id=d.con_id
```

Or add second join with con_id=0 function:

```
Select 
a.name,
a.id_no,
case when d.con_id is null then d0.dealer_name else d.dealer_name end dealer_name  ,
case when d.con_id is null then d0.address     else d.address     end address
from 
contract a
left join dealer d on a.con_id=d.con_id
left join dealer d0 on d.con_id is null and d0.con_id=0
```